# How to add React.jsx.element to firebase database?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, firebase

I have a blog site and I want to send the blog that I wrote to firebase database. But I can not. It said, the text must be a string, number, etc.

My blog like this

```
<<p pra>>
          <<h one>>
             A Glimpse into the Future of Immersive Technology
          <</h one>>
          <<br></br>>
   <<p pra>>

          In recent years, the world of virtual reality (VR) has captured the
          imagination of technology enthusiasts and gamers alike. Now, tech
          giant Apple is set to enter the virtual reality space with its highly
          anticipated VR headset. Packed with advanced features, sleek design,
          and Apple's trademark innovation, the Apple VR headset promises to
          redefine the immersive experience. In this blog post, we will delve
          into the exciting world of the Apple VR headset, its features,
          potential applications, and its impact on the future of VR technology.
   <</p pra>>
<</p pra>>
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you want to send the raw html to your Firebase database?

Comment: Use Firebase Storage or just send a long string encased in double quotes, also keep in mind that if you use / you need to put //. If that doesn't work you could try string concadenation.

Comment: @HereticMonkey exactly ,thanks ,i did not how to search

Answer (score 0):

You can use [renderToStaticMarkup](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToStaticMarkup) or [renderToString](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToString) to convert your jsx to string.